# Multiple Result Sets Using in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, dataset

Multiple Result Sets using in SSRS

I have two SP 1. have 3 parameter 2nd have 1 parameter for the purpose of if statement

How could I integrate them:

**SP1**

```
create pro summary @Runas varchar @unit ..... end
```

**SP2**

```
create SP @runas varchar
 if @runas = detail 
 begin 
   select * from tab1 
 end 
 if @runas = summary 
 begin 
   select * from tab2 
 end
end
```

In my SSRS how do I integrate them

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Could you please try elaborating? Thanks.

Comment: SSRS is not a data integration tool. This should be done in the SQL then passed to SSRS as a single dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The UNION ALL command is equal to the UNION command, except that UNION ALL selects all values.

The difference between Union and Union all is that Union all will not eliminate duplicate rows, instead it just pulls all rows from all tables fitting your query specifics and combines them into a table.

Have you thought of Union?